# When in wolf form using Wild Shape, can you wield a sword in you mouth?

Tags: druid, wild-shape, pathfinder-2e

When in wolf form using Wild Shape, can you wield a sword in you mouth?

I think it's possible. As long as the sword's not too big it won't weigh down the head, and the strength of a wolf is strong enough to use one. Nowhere does it say that the animal cant interact with an object that it has the capability to wield.

Comment: The reason we need to know is that the first and second editions of Pathfinder are completely different and separate games each with their own set of rules. An answer about the rules for one is meaningless for the other. Therefore, knowing which edition of Pathfinder you are actually playing is important.

Comment: I pritty sure were using 2nd edition

Comment: Some of your comments indicate that you may be actually playing Pathfinder-1e. Can you verify *for sure* what edition you are playing? If it helps, Pathfinder 2e officially came out at the beginning of last month, so if you have been playing your system longer than that, then you are likely playing PF-1e.

Answer (score 9):

## Rule-wise: no

A wolf can *carry* a sword in its mouth no problem, but 'wielding' is a specific term in Pathfinder, and distict from carrying.

I can *carry* a greatsword in one hand, holding it, having it with me, all that good stuff.
If I wish to *wield* it (hold it in such a way that I can use it for the intended purpose), I will need a second hand.

So your wolf form can carry the weapon around, and perhaps even hit someone with it like a club, but you won't have the grip and manual dexterity to use it as a sword.

Comment: What about martial one handed weapons. Like a scimitar. It can be wielded in one hand or off. The measure of how much effort it takes to use a weapon (whether the weapon is designed as a light, one-handed, or two-handed for a particular wielder) is altered by one step for each size category differents from the wielders size and the size of the creature for which the weapon was designed. The weapons size category isn't the same as its size as a object. If a weapons designation be changed to something other than light, one-handed, two-handed by this alternation the creature can't use it.

Comment: @Wolfblade As you just said, one-handed weapons require at least one hand to wield. A mouth is zero hands. (Presumably, a mouth doesn’t have the dexterity or correct grip to hold or use right, or to compensate for shocks during hits.)

Comment: The weapon is not changed at all. Its still one-handed, has right size, and it doesn't say that the creature cant be a animal. And the weapon doesn't use that much effort. So why I use Wildshape as a wolf and use a one handed weapon. I retain my Intelligence, charisma, and all. The only thing that changes I think is the dexterity, and strength. Which a wolf has enough of to wield it. Though do the proficiently carry over? Plus game the ones of the creature? If so then I would be proficient with the scimitar.

Comment: @Wolfblade I think SevenSidedDie's point is that, even if the wolf has the necessary strength and dexterity, a mouth is still a mouth and not a hand. Though I'm not familiar with Pathfinder rules, it sounds like a one-handed weapon specifically requires at least one hand to use, or possibly an equivalent appendage, and a wolf's mouth probably doesn't count as being equivalent. Feel free though to run this by your GM. They might like the idea enough to let you use it.

Comment: @Wolfblade try putting a broomstick into your mouth and see how well you can hit things with it. A wolf will have a stronger bite yes, but you'll note that bite strength isn't the limiting factor here, it's the fact you can't get a proper grip on it or move it in a way even vaguely resembling a strike because your head or neck doesn't have the mobility required. This doesn't work in any way.

Comment: I'm not thinking of strikes like trying to stab. More of slashes. Dart between legs slashing them. Jumping past them slashing there thighs. Maybe if a situation occurs jump at them, knock them down then slash the neck. The feat Slashing grace will do the piercing.

Comment: Should I use a long dagger or machete instead? That would get the job done.

Comment: @Wolfblade It seems you feel very strongly that creatures should be able to wield weapons in their mouths, which is a really neat idea! However, the only thing we can tell you is what the rules say about that (which is what ThisIsMe is explaining in their answer). Have you tried asking your DM what they think? Your DM can always make rulings outside the rules if they think it is appropriate.

Comment: @Wolfblade hold up - are you playing Pathfinder 1e or Pathfinder 2e? The question is tagged as Pathfinder 2e, but you're using a whole lot of terms in these comments that don't exist in Pathfinder 2e - light weapons, the weapon size category stuff isn't mentioned, Wildshape doesn't change stats around, Slashing Grace doesn't exist... And *in general* things aren't easily transferable between the editions.

Comment: @Wolfblade Slash or stab doesn't make any difference. You won't be able to put any force behind it. Again, I invite you to try, surely you'll have some long stick-like thing at or around home.